# Manually failing a build after it's complete

Tags: jenkins

Is it possible to set the build result for a build after that build is complete?

I could not find any plugins that do this already, and I was considering writing my own, but I wanted to see if this was even possible before going down that path.

(I have looked at existing code and how the "Fail The Build" plugin works as an example, but my understanding of the Jenkins code base is not advanced enough to understand what all the possibilities are.)

Use case: we have a build pipeline, and near the end of the pipeline there is a deploy-to-qa step that deploys the artifact to a QA environment. We have automated tests before this step to try to catch any problems with the artifact, but our test coverage is not very high in some areas so bugs could still slip through the cracks. I'd like to have the ability to mark a deploy-to-qa build as FAILED after the fact, to denote that that particular pipeline was invalid and is not a candidate for production release. (Basically the same as [this Build Pipeline Plugin issue](http://code.google.com/p/build-pipeline-plugin/issues/detail?id=101))

Comment: Changing build status will only achieve change in ball color (I assume, I have not tested that). Are you sure that's what you want, especially if tests actually succeeded in reality?

Comment: Basically what I'm looking for is, if I ask for the lastSuccessful build for the job, then a build that was failed post-completion would not qualify.

Comment: Correct solution to the use case is to use the [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin), which will give you separate flag showing whether the build passed the tests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some more investigation in the code, I believe that this is not possible.

From `hudson.model.Run`:

```
public void setResult(Result r) {
    // state can change only when we are building
    assert state==State.BUILDING;

    // snip
    ...
}
```

So the build result cannot change except when in "building" state.

I could try to muck with the lastSuccessful and lastStable symlinks (as is done with the `delete()` function in `hudson.model.AbstractBuild`), but then those would be reset as soon as Jenkins reloaded the build results from `jobs/JOBNAME/builds/`.

Answer (score 2):

I have an untested suggestion: Make a parametrized build, where the parameter determines if build will fail or not (for example simple bat / shell script testing the parameter from the environment variable it sets, and doing exit 0 or exit 1). This assumes that build pipelines manually triggered step will ask the parameters, and not use default values.

If it does not support interactive build parameters, then some other way is needed to tell this extra build step wether it should fail or not. Maybe editing upstream build description or display name to indicate failure, and then allowing build pipeline to continue to this extra build step, which probably has to use system groovy script to dig out upstream build description or display name.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen several debates on this topic previously, and the outcome was always that it is theoretically possible to do so, but the codebase is not designed to allow this and it would have to be a very hacky workaround.

It's also been said that this is a bad practice in general, although I don't remember what the argument against it was.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear what the arguments against it were, since (code design aside), it seems to be the simplest solution to the use case presented in my question.

Comment: I believe it all came down to the concept that a build pipeline should always be forward looking. So if a build passed based on your tests and criteria at the time it was built, then it should stay that way. If you need to eliminate a build from being deployed after manual QA, you should have a pipeline step which would push to an artifact server, or artifact location only after successfully passing the manual QA process.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same requirement. I haven't found an appropriate plugin, changing the build status is not just a flag but has other impacts on links (eg latest successful build etc). So instead of changing the status of the build I looked for a possibility for qualifying the build. The [Promoted Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Promoted+Builds+Plugin) apply flags to build to define e.g. different quality stages. Build promotions can be performed manually or based on e.g. downstream project successful builds. Any successful build can be qualified, based on the promotion additional build and post build actions can be executed, e.g tagging or archiving.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was able to do it by changing the `build.xml` manually to `<result>FAILURE</result>`.

I've then played a little bit with `mklink` to create some symbolic links and also renamed the lastSuccessfulBuild to lastFailedBuild and it worked. If you are allowed to access the filesystem from within a Jenkins PlugIn, then it is possible to write one.

In case you are fine to delete the current build and start the same build using a version number and setting the next BUILD_NUMBER to the deleted one, then you could use this plugin to tell it to fail instead of succeed:

[Fail The Build Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Fail+The+Build+Plugin)

Comment: This is working don't forget to restart Jenkins after fixing the symlinks because rest API queries will continue to return wrong build number:
Before restart
$ curl -n http://localhost/job/myjob/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber
11
After restart
$ curl -n http://localhost/job/myjob/lastSuccessfulBuild/buildNumber
13

Comment: @FilipStefanov, a restart isn't necessary. Just use the "Manage Jenkins > Reload Configuration from Disk"